# How to accomplish center alignment with float

Tags: css

I'm trying to center all 3 divs. Is there a way to get this done without creating a wrap around div2 and div3.

```
               div1  | div2 |  div3
------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: is there any code to show ?

Comment: What kind of wrap? Is `<body>` (e.g.) eligible?

Comment: @minitech, the wrap will be just an extra div that wraps div2 and 3, but I don't want to go that route if an alternative is possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try something like this, as body will most probably be present:

```
<body>
    <div class="centered" id="a">A</div>
    <div class="centered" id="b">B</div>
    <div class="centered" id="c">C</div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```css
body {
    text-align: center;
}

.centered {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/crsAC/)